# Modular Arithmetic problem

Tags: encryption

Having confusion. Plaintext = 25, Key=15 and modulus =26.
Cipher=(15 + 25) mod 26=14.
Now , plaintext = (15-14) mod 26=1

Here I am not getting the plaintext correctly. How to do it?

Comment: Why 15-14? 14-15.

Answer (score 1):

Let CT be the ciphertext, PT the plaintext, K the key, n the modulus.

Since `CT=(PT+K) mod n`, `PT=(CT-K) mod n`. In your case, `PT=(14-15) mod 26= -1 mod 26=25`, as expected. Remember that for x<0, `x mod n= (n+x) mod n` (not n-x, as -x would be positive) by definition.

What you did was `PT=(K-CT) mod n`, which is not true, because this would imply `PT=(K-(PT+K)) mod n= -PT mod n`, which in general is not true.

For example, `10 mod 26=10`, while `-10 mod 26=(26-10) mod 26=16`, and clearly 10 is not 16.

In fact, this is only true for `PT=n/2`(and its multiples) because only in that case `PT=(n-PT) mod n`.

Comment: Okay. Understood the solution. So PT=(CT-K) mod N is giving the correct answer. Thank you ☺

Comment: One more thing, if  I use CT=(PT +K1+K2) mod N, then PT=(K2-K1-CT)mod N. Is it correct?

Comment: @avisekmanna No, it's PT=(CT-K1-K2) mod n. First, CT, then the key or keys. Indeed, if you consider K=K1+K2 as a single key, applying the formula I wrote in my answer you have PT=(CT-K) mod n, which is (CT-(K1+K2)) mod n or, equivalently, (CT-K1-K2) mod n.